# How to get the country states info in Android?

Tags: android, localization

Is it possible to get all register states of country using Android API?

Example:

Using Android Local API i can find the country code, like US, but using the same country code is it possible to me to get the states,

like:

String[] statesName = Local.get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API in the Android SDK to find out if a given country has smaller organizational units (states, provinces, etc.), let alone what they are.